# Unity destroying player outside of boundary box (Saving positions in a for loop)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like some help with figuring this out as my brain is having a funny day today at what is the best way to go about this.

I have an OnDrawGizmos as follows

```
    Transform parentBounds;

void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    parentBounds = this.gameObject.transform;

    Vector3 from;
    Vector3 to;
    for (int a = 0; a < parentBounds.childCount; a++)
    {
        from = parentBounds.GetChild(a).position;
        to = parentBounds.GetChild((a + 1) % parentBounds.childCount).position;

        Gizmos.color = new Color(1, 0, 0);
        Gizmos.DrawLine(from, to);
    }
}
```

This code is attached on a "parent" object which contains 4 empty game objects as follows

[image]

Which produces the following Gizmo (Drawing a square based on where I put the empty objects within the parent)

[image]

I can even add more points if I desire.

---

**SO WHAT IS THE PROBLEM ?**

What I need is that if the player is not within this box area, I want the player to be destroyed. I'm not sure what the best practice is for this , should I make an array to hold the xmin, ymax, etc. ? or should I generate a new position vector on every loop ? I've tried a few ways that are not giving me the results I want and I taught to ask for some assistance.

Thank you all in advance !

Comment: If your game supports physics, I would recommend using Bounds.Contains to check if a point is inside.

Check here for more details: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.Contains.html

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! And just because you are using a certain IDE (`visual-studio`) doesn't automatically mean that this question is about that IDE

Comment: `SO WHAT IS THE PROBLEM ?` The problem is that you don't have any code at all that would do what you want .. or at least you didn't add any to your question so how shall we know what the problem could possibly be?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a 2D game (which I assume it is), how about having a script, that has reference to the player object and...

## a) game is not using physics

... a `public Rect boundaries`. On each `Update()` check if player is within the boundaries and if not - destroy it.

```
void Update()
{
    if (!boundaries.Contains(playerObject.transform.position))
    {
        Destroy(playerObject);
    }
}
```

## b) game is using physics

... a `BoxCollider2D` with the following script

```
void OnColliderExit2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    // If collider is player object -> destroy collider.gameObject
}
```